# Timeout error when try to run testcafe selenium based test using GitLab Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, testcafe

I created a test-café runner file and running a test using selenium grid. Its working fine from my machine but we need to do same operation using GitLab pipeline.

Using pipeline, I am able to connect with selenium grid server but always getting Time-out error.

When I logged into the selenium node server to check, I can see that testcafe open a chrome browser instance but not able to start the test.

Here is my pipeline error:

```
Selenium server address is set to: http://myserver:4444/wd/hub
Error: Unable to open the "selenium:chrome" browser due to the following error:
WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.[63](https://gitlab.com/automation-test/load-testing/-/jobs/2556429847#L63))
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/etc/gitlab-runner/builds/1idHsSdk/0/automation-test/load-testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:522:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/etc/gitlab-runner/builds/1idHsSdk/0/automation-test/load-testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:549:13)
    at Executor.execute (/etc/gitlab-runner/builds/1idHsSdk/0/automation-test/load-testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:475:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
    at Object.execute (/etc/gitlab-runner/builds/1idHsSdk/0/automation-test/load-testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:735:17)
    at BrowserConnection._runBrowser (/etc/gitlab-runner/builds/1idHsSdk/0/automation-test/load-testing/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/connection/index.ts:214:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
```

YAML File

```
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - node_modules/
  
stages:
   - deploy

e2e_tests:
    stage: deploy  
    tags:
       - shell-executor
    image: node:12.13.0-alpine
    before_script:
      - npm install
    script:
      - node testcafe_runner.js
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "TestCafe-TestRunner",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,  
  "devDependencies": {
      "testcafe":"1.18.6",
      "testcafe-browser-provider-selenium":"1.2.0",
      "testcafe-reporter-html":"^1.4.4",
      "testcafe-reporter-xunit":"^2.1.0",
      "find-free-port":"2.0.0",
      "node-cmd":"^3.0.0",
      "internal-ip":"6.2.0",
      "fs-extra":"^6.0.1",
      "csv-parser":"^2.3.2",
      "csv-writer":"^1.6.0"
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The [TestCafe documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402816/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab) states that you will need to use their docker image, or install `testcafe` in an image with the necessary browser runtimes you will be testing against.